# Custom Migration Plugin MySQL Error

Tags: nodes, database, drush, migrations, 9

I've run into the following error when running the command `drush migrate-import custom_spotlight`
where `custom_spotlight` is the name of the plugin. I've been following along with this guide: https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-8-migrations-part-4-migrating-nodes-drupal-7 but I'm not exactly sure what went wrong here. It seems when the placeholder `:nid` is substituted with a value, there are quotes inserted as well which displays in the error log as the HTML entity code. Any tips on how to resolve this issue? [image]

Drupal version: 9

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: One of two things is happening - the SQL query is being built incorrectly, or the value being submitted is quoted. I'd say the latter is more likely, but it could be either. You'll have to work backwards to find out where the NID is being submitted, then debug to see if/where quotes are being added in between. And also track back to find where that query is being built, and see if you can see why it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue stemmed from incorrect SQL syntax. The last column after the `SELECT` should not contain a comma.